# Table Border for an Iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to Iphone app development.
I have been trying to draw a border for my table in my iphone app. Most of the posts I see are how to remove the seperation lines between cells or change colors or add background.

I tried to do the following

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.layer.border = 1;
}
```

However, it says that the border is not an attribute.

It would be great if someone could help me out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean you'd like to display the table in 'Grouped' style, which adds a border?

[table setStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: from the linked document: 'Table views can have one of two styles, UITableViewStylePlain and UITableViewStyleGrouped. When you create a UITableView instance you must specify a table style, and **this style cannot be changed**.'

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes, it can't be changed, but the point remains that the Grouped style may be the border solution the OP is seeking.

Comment: yes.. i figured that out pretty late.. i did not think about that option.. grouped style would be the best in this type of situations... thanks for answers.. they were helpful...

Answer (score 1):

CALayer indeed does not have such property. What you need is `borderColor` and `borderWidth`